# State not updating when I use it within a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I declare a state:

```
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
```

Then I set it within a useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {

      axios
        .post("/myroute.json", { id: selectedHotel })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then((response) => {

          console.log("is updating photo list",response.data.photos)
          setThumbs(renderThumbs(response.data.photos))
          setList(response.data.photos)

        });
  }, [selectedHotel]);







  const onDragStart = (event) => {
    // We'll access the "data-position" attribute
    // of the current element dragged
    const initialPosition = Number(event.currentTarget.dataset.position);
  
    setDragAndDrop({
      // we spread the previous content
      // of the hook variable
      // so we don't override the properties 
      // not being updated
      ...dragAndDrop, 
  
      draggedFrom: initialPosition, // set the draggedFrom position
      isDragging: true, 
      originalOrder: list // store the current state of "list"
    });
  
    console.log("within OnDrag", event.currentTarget.dataset.position, dragAndDrop, list)


     ....
    
     }
```

I see in the console log with in the onDragStart, "list" always remains as `[]` but I can see in the console log of the useEffect that `response.data.photos` contains what I want to set

OnDragStart is used here:

```
    const renderThumbs = (files) => {
      return files.map((file, index) => 
     
        {
          return(
            <li data-position={index} style={thumb} key={file.id} draggable="true" onDragStart={(ev) => onDragStart(ev)}   onDragOver={(ev) => onDragOver(ev)}  onDrop={onDrop}>
            <div style={thumbInner}>
              <img
                src={file.url}
                style={img}
              />
            </div>
            <div style={thumbCloser} onClick={removeFile(file, files)}><Emoji symbol="❌" /></div>
          </li>
          )
        }
    
      );
    }
```

and it's used within the use effect to set "thumbs" which is used to render the components of the list in the DOM

Comment: Is `onDragStart` inside another React hook? Can you provide a more comprehensive code example for use to examine? It is unclear how the `onDragStart` function relates to the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: where is the selectedHotel variable?

Comment: I have updated the function where I use `onDragStart`

Comment: it's a redux state @NIKHILCHANDRAROY

Comment: I set it as ` const selectedHotel = useSelector((state) => state.hotel);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of closure, since you set thee thumbs to render within state inside useEffect which is called only once, and assign the `onDragStart` event handler to it, you are essentially using the instance of `onDragStart` along with its enclosing closure when the useEffect was called for the entire lifecycle of the component. Even when the component re-render the closure is not updated since its not defined again.

What you must do is to not store the content to be rendered in state but the data that you want to use to render

```
useEffect(() => {

      axios
        .post("/myroute.json", { id: selectedHotel })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
        .then((response) => {

          console.log("is updating photo list",response.data.photos)
          setThumbs(response.data.photos)
          setList(response.data.photos)

        });
  }, [selectedHotel]);

  ...

  return renderThumbs(thumbs);
```